# Can I use XML(SysML based) to make DB table in Agens graph database?

Tags: agens-graph

I'm a beginner in programming..
Could someone tell me about my question?

I want to know can I use SysML based XML to make DB tables in Agens DB.

Is there anyone who knows this?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard SysML is a tool for Relational DB modeling. AgensGraph has added graph model process to PostgreSQL. 
So if you want to import XML, there is no difference between AgensGraph and PostgreSQL.
Google it with keywords like 'postgresql import xml schema'.
I've done it and there is not any formal tools for importing xml, you would have to do some script programming.